# Specific approximation of sums with integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, approximation, riemann-sum

These two approximations are given in my book. $$ \sum_{k=0}^m\left(\frac{k}{m}\right)^n\approx\int_0^m\left(\frac{x}{m}\right)^ndx\tag{1}$$

$$\sum_{i=m+1}^n\frac{1}{i-1}\approx\int_m^n\frac{1}{x}dx\tag{2}$$

I would like some explanation of why they are true and what does the "approximately" mean. Is it convergence in the limit or is it just close.

Comment: I think you left out an exponent in $(1)$.

Comment: Did you forget the nth power in the first expression rhs?

Comment: Made the edit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Write the RHS integral as a Riemann sum with the constant rectangle width. Pretty sure you intended $\int_0^m (x/m)^n dx$

Comment: I still need help with the second approximation

Comment: @johnson exactly the same idea, sum on the left is $$\frac1m + \frac{1}{m+1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n-1},$$ LHS-evaluations of Riemann rectangles...

Comment: I get that they are areas of rectangles. But how can we say they are approximately the same. Furthermore does the approximation get better if we increase the number of terms?

Comment: @johnson yes: more rectangles on the same interval means smaller rectangle width, which means a better approximation of the curve. To see how they are the same, draw a picture -- as the number of rectangles increases, the sum on LHS converges to the RHS

Comment: The rectangle widths are not getting smaller in the above two formulas if we increase the number of terms. i.e. for the second formula, increase the upper bound from n to n + 10 say. I guess the approximation error gets worse and worse. So how justified are we in using the approximation. Is it only for convenience because the integral is easier to handle.